# ¿Es posible seleccionar varios datos insertados en un jList en java?

Tags: java, netbeans

¿Como puedo seleccionar 3 datos de una lista en java?

Con este codigo solo puedo seleccionar un valor de la lista, necesito seleccionar 3 de ellos y guardarlos en cada una de las variables `String` que allí aparecen.

```
String apunt,apunt2,apunt3; 

if(ListaUno.isSelectionEmpty()){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " 
Seleccione un valor de la Lista "); } 
else{ 
apunt=ListaUno.getSelectedValue(); Ley obj=new Ley(); obj.setDato(apunt); 
obj.setModelo(modelo); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"es"); [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
}
```

Comment: Explica mejor lo que necesitas, qué has intentado, y presenta tu código.

Comment: Tengo un apuntador para seleccionar un numero de la lista, necesito que ese apuntador me selecciones 3 números distintos y los guarde en 3 variables diferentes.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta te puede ayudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234893/jlist-select-multiple-items

Comment: Vete echando un ojo a cómo hacer preguntas ([tour]) antes de que te cierren esta

Comment: Disculpa amigo, la verdad esto me tiene un poco desconcertado

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que setear este atributo de tu lista:

```
JList lista = new JList();
lista.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

//este retorna un array de los valores seleccionados
lista.getSelectedIndices();

//Este retorna una lista de los valores seleccionados
lista.getSelectedValuesList();
```

A consideracion propia sabras que utilizar

Comment: ok voy a intentar, gracias amigo.